# print repeating string with f-string

Tags: f-string, python-3.11

I can `print(‘#’*5)` to >>> `#####.`

But if I try to do this with f-string like

```
a=5
print(f” ‘#’*{a}”)
```

I get >>> `‘#’*5`.
Is this not possible, or what is my failure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
a=5
print(f"{'#'*a}")
```

To get

```
#####
```